# Anonymous Page in SharePoint Online

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, anonymous

there is a requirement in my project to create couple of anonymous pages in SharePoint Online for guest users. I know this is possible with SharePoint On Premise, however just wanted to check if its possible in SharePoint Online also to create anonymous pages, because in SharePoint Online, its always required to authenticate the user against Azure Active Directory.

Business Scenario - Guest users should be able to access 1-2 anonymous pages, after that they need to login into the application to access further application features and functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous access **is not** supported in SPO sites from safety reasons and because sharing with external users is well done through Azure Active Directory.

However, the "anonymous page" behavior can be reproduced in SPO as following:

- Go to **Microsoft 365 admin center**
- Select **SharePoint**
- Go to **Sites** and select **Active Sites**
- Select the Site Collection you want, go to **Policies** and select "Anyone" radio button

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lm9Y.png)

Also, when doing this be careful at what you have set here: Microsoft 365 admin center->Policies->Sharing (do not forget to pay attention on safety and security)

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYgmu.png)

Basically, all you need can be achieved by using the **Admin center**. This link contains more details on what I have described: https://code2care.org/tutorial/how-to-enable-anonymous-public-access-microsoft-office-365-sharepoint-online-site-collection-file-folder-without-login

Hope it helps, best regards!